# How upload and download file direct to Virtual Server use Terminal

Tags: file-upload, command-line, download, ibm-cloud, virtual-server

I need upload about 600 kiB C file and make file directory (local computer) to IBM Cloud Virtual Server and compile C files there. After program finish work, download result file, file size 5 MiB to 25 MiB back to local computer. Want use Mac OS X or Linux command line Terminal for upload and download.

Already have IBM Command Line Tool installed and know how select start/pause/stop virtual servers use web console with SSH key file. Can SSH to virtual servers.

Only use virtual server for extra computer power. No need Object Storage Bucket, no need web application, no deploy web application, Docker, no need fancy stuff in IBM Cloud documents, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use scp to copy your files to the VSI using it's credentials. It's no different than copying a file over to a remote server.
https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp
or use an sftp client like filezilla or cyberduck